# auto generate in LINQ to SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a table whit 2 columns , ID and name .I set 'YES' Identity for ID column  .

I want to insert data to table whit LINQ .I want to get only name column from user in my application , and then ID column fill automatic to database and I can't give data that column and fill whitout I give it .

What should I do ?

I write in c# and work whit LINQ .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So your database field already is a INT IDENTITY - right?

Next, in your LINQ to SQL designer, you need to make sure your column is set to:

- Auto Generated Value = TRUE
- Auto-Sync   = ON INSERT

[image]

Now if you add an entry to your database, the ID will be automatically updated from the value assigned to it by the database:

```
YourClass instance = new YourClass();
instance.Name = "some name";

YourDataContext.InsertOnSubmit(instance);
YourDataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

After the SubmitChanges call, your `instance.ID` should now contain the ID from the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you used the DBML designer, that should be setup correctly.

The 'id' will be populated after you call SubmitChanges.

Comment: How do I do this work?
it is my problem that I can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your database table is setup correctly and that your ID is set as the primary key field and to auto increment.  Regenerate your DBML if you need to by deleting the object and re-adding it.  It should know that the ID is not needed and the auto fill it once the insert has succeeded.